# MVC 4 Validation firing, but the form is still submitting?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

My MVC 4 validation is working as it seems, the error messages pop up, but it still submits the form.  Any idea what I am missing?  Thank you.

```
public class StatusRequestModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ticket Number")]
    public int? TicketNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public int? PostalCode { get; set; }
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TicketNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TicketNumber)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PostalCode)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PostalCode)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset"  value="Reset"/>
}
```

Comment: Can you post the some code?

Comment: Posted, - validation summary is popping up, but the post is still happening

Comment: What script libraries are you loading on the page?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb but the reason your form is still submitting is because both properties in your model are nullabe which have a value when null. If you could also include your action it could shed more light on what's actually happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you have the following JS libraries referenced in your code:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

Ensure you have the following `appSettings` entries in your web.config file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

You can also enable client validation in the view instead of the config file if you wish:

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

Comment: greg, this may well be the answer but seems very speculative from such an experienced poster

Comment: Yes, I'm speculating that I'm right :) But seriously, I can't see why it wouldn't work if all the above is in place.

Comment: I apparently just had some incompatible JS libraries running alongside - got rid of those.  Thank you guys for the help, I was going nuts - you helped me confirm I wasn't losing it!

Answer (score 3):

greg84's answer is the correct answer in terms of what needs to be included to the project. But for me, I also had the problem of the jquery.validate plugin not working with jquery > 1.9.0. Once I changed it to the jquery 1.8.3, it worked.