# Strange behavior in Unobtrusive validation in ASP.NET MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and I am experiencing a strange behavior with the JQuery Unobtrusive Validation.

I have placed its related scripts into my layout.cshtml and when I open up the view and hit the submit button, the validation messages are coming and up and suddenly the server call is hit. i.e the debugger steps into the server code for POST event.

So basically, both the things are happening here. The client side validation as well as the server side event.

I can see the messages firing up yet the execution seems to continue and go to server side.

This is my view code :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Registration", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frm1" }))
        {
            //some HTML markup
            .
            .
            .
            <div class="col-md-1 divside-left-first">
                <button type="submit" value="Save" id="Btnsave" class="btn ui-state-default medium">&nbsp;Submit&nbsp;</button>
            </div>
        }
```

I have placed the following scripts into the layout.cshtml file *at the bottom* and they are rendered properly on the browser. I checked.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Apart from that, I haven't used any other scripts with these except the native JQuery.js script.

Things I have already tried :

- Putting scripts *on the top section*. Didn't work.
- Changing button type from button to input. Didn't work.
- Tried putting scripts into section view instead of layout.cshtml. Didn't work.

Any help or suggestion as to what I am doing wrong here or not getting would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` (that's only for the `Ajax()` helpers)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Well let me remove it now and check and get back.

Comment: where is the jQuery.js ? is it loaded ? this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136900/mvc-4-validation-firing-but-the-form-is-still-submitting. In addition do you have a server side code for ModelState.IsValid in your "AddUser" action in the controller ? this might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436284/jquery-post-still-goes-through-inspite-of-asp-net-mvc-4-validation-failure

Comment: @Mortalus - The jquery file is loaded safely and properly. And yes, I do have kept Server side validation just in case. But that is not the expected behavior.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - As we expected, it didn't affect anything. Still the same as it is

Comment: just a thought might it be because you use a <button> tag and not an <input> tag that the scripts of MVC are not configured to prevent the submitting of the form by a <button> tag ?

Comment: @Mortalus - So you are suggesting to put input tags instead of button tags ?

Comment: @MattMurdock yes I am...

Comment: @Mortalus - Let me try that and get back.

Comment: @Mortalus - That didn't work out. Its tricky what might be happening here.

Comment: @MattMurdock Are you submitting the form with jQuery or just the normal submit button click?

Comment: How did you wire-up the inputs for validation ? check this : http://www.mobzystems.com/blog/setting-up-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt - I am submitting through a simple `<input type='submit'>`.

Comment: @BrilBroeder - I just placed the required scripts in the layout file and provided data annotations on my model. With this, it automatically generates the required attributes. And while it does call the validations on submit, it also postbacks simultaneously. And that is what I am not able to rectify here.

Comment: If you hit a submit button it will always postsback. What you can do is capture the submit event using jquery and 'do something/do checks' and if you decide that a submit can proceed return false. http://api.jquery.com/submit/ Most of the time I do not use submit buttons but onclick event on buttons and then, if neccesary do the submit. Gives you more control over the flow.

Comment: @BrilBroeder, OP is using `query.validate.js`. It will not submit if there are validation errors (that's what the script does - i.e. cancels the submit event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for almost one day, I finally happened to found out the solution for this *in my case*. It could be something else for any one, but in my case this seemed to work :

The issue with with the JQuery version that I was using and the unobtrusive validation JS. They seemed to be not going well together and I observed an error stating **"Unexpected token u"** in the browser console whenever a POST event occured.

So while exploring that error in depth, I came to know that there was some kind of conflict between those two JS files and you need to use one additional JS file that would help eliminate the differences and make them work perfectly together. That file is :

**jquery.migrate**

You just need to add this JS file reference in your code and make sure that all other JS files are in proper place and then run your code. It was working as expected after this.

Hope this helps.